# Using my own format function with `log4-clj-format`

Tags: clojure, log4j

I'm looking at [log4-clj-layout](https://github.com/uswitch/log4-clj-layout) to bring a little order to the mess that is logging in Java. I'd like play around a little with a format function of my own, but I'm failing at getting it to work.

Following the instructions on the page above I started with adding the following to my `log4j.properties` file:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout=log4_clj_layout.layout.Layout
log4j.appender.console.layout.FormatFn=json-format
```

That worked beautifully. Then I added a function, `log-test.core/my-format` and tried to use that for logging:

```
log4j.appender.console.layout=log4_clj_layout.layout.Layout
log4j.appender.console.layout.FormatFn=log-test.core/my-format
```

But now all I get is an error when starting:

```
(log/warn "foo")
Setting format-fn: log-est.core/my-format
log4j:WARN Failed to set property [formatFn] to value "log-test.core/my-format". 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
...
```

Clearly I'm missing something, but what?

I defined my format function like this (`l` is an alias for `log4-clj-layout.layout`):

```
(defn my-format [event]
  (pr event)
  (l/json-format event))
```

Any and all help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you make sure that `my-format` is inside the namespace `log-est.core`? Also, usually an `InvocationTargetException` wraps another exception. Is there more to the stack trace you didn't paste?